# No margin-bottom on bootstrap button?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I’m using button element in a bootstrap template.

I was wondering if it is the normal behavior in bootstrap :

When there is not enough space to show all the buttons on one line, or when the window is resized, some buttons are shown on a 2nd line and it’s ok like that but there is no margin-bottom.

I can add it :

```
.btn {
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
```

But i find it strange that it is not handled by bootstrap.

Maybe i’m doing something wrong ?

**SOURCE** : http://jsfiddle.net/Vinyl/zx9oefya/

[image]

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_plus_infos" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#plus_infos">Plus d'infos</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_plus_infos" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#plus_infos">Plus d'infos</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn_plus_infos" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#plus_infos">Plus d'infos</button>
```

Comment: I think Bootstrap is expecting you to use responsive markup to handle this...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Bootstrap's `buttons.less` and `button-groups.less` there's nothing about margin-top or margin-bottom. Having a margin by default would likely conflict when combining it with other elements (e.g. a form)

I think the best solution might be adding all buttons inside a `btn-toolbar` and to style that combination:

```
.btn-toolbar .btn {
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
}
```

Comment: You are correct. If used inside a form-group it has a margin on the .form-group, inside a <p> it also does the same thing. If you look at bootstrap's examples, they write a class to add margin for the demo only.

Answer (score 5):

Just add the spacing class. `m` for margin and `p` for padding.

```
 <button class="btn btn-success mr-2" type="submit">Add</button>
 <button class="btn btn-danger mr-2" type="button">Delete</button>
```

so, here `mr` is margin-right. similarly, you can add do for other cases.

Answer (score 5):

`mb-5 = margin bottom` ..just add that :) sorted :)

Comment: How’s this different from other answers??

Comment: mb = margin bottom is a shortcut that noone has mentioned and you can simply add it into the line.

Answer (score 4):

I think that it's the normal behavior ( not 100% sure ) because it's "cleaner" to add margin ourselves when we want it that having to remove the default margin when we don't want it, from my opinion...

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups

There's no `margin` on bootstrap's buttons examples, only on the parent `div` class `btn-group` but it's coming from a different stylesheet ( docs.min.css ). So I think it's that way for devs to add their own custom `margin`s.

See here:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap 5, they have change the syntax a little bit, it can be found here: [Spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/spacing/).

The format is: `{property}{sides}-{size}`.

The property is `m` for margin, `p` for padding.

The sides is one of:

- t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top
- b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom
- s - (start) for classes that set margin-left or padding-left in LTR, margin-right or padding-right in RTL
- e - (end) for classes that set margin-right or padding-right in LTR, margin-left or padding-left in RTL
- x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right
- y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom
- blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

The size is one of the:

- 0 - for classes that eliminate the margin or padding by setting it to 0
- 1 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .25
- 2 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * .5
- 3 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer
- 4 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 1.5
- 5 - (by default) for classes that set the margin or padding to $spacer * 3
- auto - for classes that set the margin to auto